# How to retrieve adb shell output for string type command?

Tags: android, terminal, automated-tests, adb, instrumentation

Usually when I ran my tests I were using following command pattern:

> adb shell am instrument -w -r -e package com.myapp.package_with_tests
>   com.example.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Because I could include `-r` parameters I was reading test output in real time and my custom-made software was using this output for more advanced logging.

Lately Android Orchestrator was announced and in order to use it, [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-command-line) tells us to use:

> adb shell 'CLASSPATH=$(pm path android.support.test.services)
>   app_process / \
>         android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -w -e \
>         targetInstrumentation com.example.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner \
>         android.support.test.orchestrator/.AndroidTestOrchestrator'

Problem here is that general template looks like this:

> adb shell 'some_string_command'

And there `-r` becomes encapsulated in some other process and I am unable to retrieve output from tests anymore in real time. Actually output after all tests have finished is:

> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=
>
> Time: 0
>
> OK (0 tests)

Which is incorrect because I had 13 test cases running...

**Do you have any idea how can I retrieve output of that process in real time?**